# My responsive images are overlapping my header.

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hey i've created a jsfiddle to show you the problem.  My text is being overlapped by my responsive images.  I want them to sit above the text, and not do that.  Can anybody figure this out?

Heres the fiddle of it broken

http://jsfiddle.net/uqqjm2fL/

This is my css for the images and problem:

```
    .page-header .logo img {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) !important;
    top: 45%;
    left: 35.5%;
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    }

    .page-header h1 {
    margin: 30px 50px 10px;
    }

    .text-center {
    text-align: center;
    }

    .page-header h1 {
    margin: 30px 50px 10px;
    }

    h1 {
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    font-size: 54px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #555;
    }
    .page-header img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    }

    .page-header {
    position: relative;
    margin: -50px -50px 35px;
    padding: 0 0 35px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    }
```

Comment: Do you want the logo to be on top of the slider like that?

Comment: Yup, thats exactly where I want it.

Comment: And you want your logo to be based on %...? I noticed you have a width, height, top, and left using %.

Comment: Well, I want the logo to resize with the image behind it.  But stay in the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, your code is a mess. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but I'll try explaining what I can.

Your logo has a position of absolute which allows it to be on top of the slider, but because it has a % for it's location and size, it's hard to prevent it from moving around or increasing in size. Having that said... your logo basically has a size and location relative to the container's size and that container `<div class="logo">` doesn't have a set width or height so its size is dependant on its container which is page header... and that too doesn't have a set width or height so it's relative to the body.

You have several solutions. The first and best choice is to clean your code up and actually decide on a set location/size for the logo or the logo's container.

The second is to inject a new div that has a position of relative but has the same size of the logo. This way, if the logo increases in size, the newly created invisible div would also increase and push the content down so that it doesn't get overlapped by the logo.

Of course, keep in mind that because your logo's location is % based (top: 45% etc), the newly created div will move the logo because the body's size will be increased (the container for everything). Your logo will also be stretched because of the %'s as well.

Comment: Ok, I wan't to clean up the code and make it work properly.  Could you explain how I set my sizes for the logo and it's conatiner?  What I want to happen is, when the page is resized, the logo stay over the other image, in the correct location.  And if the text below it is long, not have the logo overlap it.

Answer (score 0):

after modify your code,may be solution is :[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9ghu6set/)

```css
.page-header .logo {
position: absolute;
border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) !important;
top: 20%;
left: 35.5%;
width: 30%;
z-index:99;
}
.page-header .logo img{
height:100%;
width:100%;
}

.page-header h1 {
margin: 30px 50px 10px;
}

.text-center {
text-align: center;
}

.page-header h1 {
margin: 30px 50px 10px;
}

h1 {
margin: 0 0 30px;
font-size: 54px;
font-weight: 300;
color: #555;
}
.page-header img {
width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.page-header {
position: relative;
margin: -50px -50px 35px;
padding: 0 0 35px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}
```

```html
<div class='page-header'>
   
            <div class='carousel' id='portfolio-carousel'>
    <div class='logo'>
              <img alt="Profile default" src="http://placehold.it/210x199" />
            </div>
              <img alt="Store background" src="http://placehold.it/700X394" />
            </div>
            
            <!-- end carousel -->
            <div class='row'>
              <div class='col-lg-12'>
                <div class='text-center'>
                  <br>
                  <h1>
                    lkj
                  </h1>
                  <p class='lead'>
                    alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkjser alkj
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```